# ID3v2 library for streaming mp3 files?

Tags: java, streaming, mp3

Hey,can anyone guide me to the easiest java mp3 library for reading ID3v2 tags.

Update 1:

I forgot to mention that I need to stream the mp3 on a seek bar and therefore need a mp3 library which can read length by downloading minimum content.

Comment: Seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73147/i-need-an-id3-tag-reader-library-for-java-preferably-a-fast-one  and several others http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+id3+mp3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) in the past.

Simple enough?

```
Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File("SomeMp3File.mp3");
System.out.println("Length of this mp3 in seconds is: " + mp3file.getLengthInSeconds());
if(mp3file.hasId3v2Tag()) {
   ID3v2 id3v2tag = mp3file.getId3v2Tag();
   System.out.println("The artist in the ID3v2 tag is: " + id3v2tag.getArtist());

   id3v2tag.setArtist("A new artist");
   mp3file.save("ASavedMp3File.mp3");
   System.out("Saved mp3 file with new name and artist set to 'A new artist'");
}
```

Comment: Ya but can I know the length of the mp3 file without downloading it through it??

Answer (score 1):

I have used [JAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) java library for my online mp3 player project. It provides excellent support for MP3 ID3v1, ID3v1.1, ID3v2.2, v2.3 and v2.4.